# Difficulty in send parameters in jqgrid

Tags: html, jqgrid

I have to send an authenticity token with `jqgrid` edit `url`. The problem is the `url` and parameter have different values.

Started POST

```
"/users-jqedit/?authenticity_token=hSn3r02sT3w15HY+dNjpYvUuXxWclpXz
RKJnfMBJSkQ="
```

but the parameter is

```
Parameters:{"authenticity_token"=>
"hSn3r02sT3w15HY dNjpYvUuXxWclpXzRKJnfMBJSkQ="}
```

resulting in a Can't verify CSRF token authenticity error.

Any clues? here is the code

```
$(function () {
 $("#list").jqGrid({
       url:'/users-jq', 
       editurl:"/users-jqedit/?authenticity_token=<%=form_authenticity_token.to_s%>",
```

Comment: Sorry, but what parameters exactly you **want to send**? You wrote what is wrong, but didn't clear described which information and where expect your server side. Do you probably need to place `authenticity_token` in the **body** of POST request instead of in URL parameters? Or you need to place the authenticity_token in HTTP header? What expect your server?

Comment: I wanted to send a authenticity_token. Which has a + sign and the authenticity fails because the + is replaced by a space. My server side code is not even touched because of invalid authenticity_token in the parameters. I am on rails-4 btw. @Oleg . I have fixed the issue with a gsub('+','%2B') though worried this will happen for other characters

Comment: Why don't you url encode your string?  seems this is perl ... so URI:Escape (uri_escape)

Comment: @Asieh when editing, please note that inline code spans (`like this`) [shouldn't be used for highlighting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990), only for code in sentences. Also, please try and improve the post as much as possible when editing to save the reviewers time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem then you need use

```js
editurl: "/users-jqedit/?authenticity_token=" +
    encodeURIComponent("<%=form_authenticity_token.to_s%>"),
```

instead of

```js
editurl:"/users-jqedit/?authenticity_token=<%=form_authenticity_token.to_s%>",
```